# Using custom symbols

Tags: c#, output, windows

How can I use custom symbols in a string which will be used in a `TextBox` in C# Windows Forms application?

I need to create a mathematical output using symbols like integrals, fractions and exponents. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you talking about UI? Which technology? WPF?

Comment: @Simon Opelt, I've edited the question to include the information. Thanks

Comment: And you only need to output/display? No input? Printing? Where does the data come from? Or is it just a very limited set of situations which should be displayed?

Comment: @Simon Opelt, The input is done using regular symbols only, and I would probably leave it as it is. I will only need to display the output _ no additional functionality like copying will be supported. I want the output to have a better look, like it does in Mathematica or other similar programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Programs` > `Accessories` > `System Tools` > `Character Map`. Select the font "Arial Unicode MS". Group by `Unicode Subrange`.  This opens a "Group By" Window. Select `Mathematical Operators`.

[image]

[image]

Of course you can use any font that includes these special mathematical operators.

---

**UPDATE**

If you still need to create your own symbols, you can use a font editor to do so. But creating or changing a font is not so easy. A good editor is [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/files/) (open source).